# Como ler um valor a partir de uma chave do Registro

Tags: windows, vb.net

Estou tentando pegar um valor da chave de registro porém o valor retorna vazio, alguém tem outra forma de obter o valor da chave de registro?

Segue o codigo em VB.NET

```
Private Sub ObterNomeDeRede()

Dim ValorRegistro = 
My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows 
NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\NewNetWorks", "NetworkList", Nothing)

MsgBox(ValorRegistro, vbInformation)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu tentei usar o mesmo código e também não retornou nenhum valor, embora a chave exista no *Registry* do Windows. Tentei então dessa forma:

```
Dim regKey = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
   "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\NewNetworks")
Dim value = regKey.GetValue("NetworkList")
```

Mas ele dava erro na segunda linha, dizendo que a variável `regKey` não continha valor (exceção `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`).

Eu executei então o [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), da Sysinternals, filtrando apenas as atividades do *Registry* e descobri que o programa estava tentando na realidade acessar essa chave (note a sub-chave *WOW6432Node* que foi adicionada): `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\NewNetworks`.

O meu Windows é 64-bit, então logo imaginei que o programa estava rodando em 32-bit. Para ter certeza, coloquei dois *labels* no Form para verificar duas coisas, se o sistema operacional era 64-bit e se a aplicação era 64-bit:

```
   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

      Is64BitOsLabel.Text = $"Is 64-bit OS: {Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem}"
      Is64BitAppLabel.Text = $"Is 64-bit App: {Is64BitApp()}"

   End Sub

   Private Function Is64BitApp() As Boolean

      Return IntPtr.Size = 8

   End Function
```

*(O código para a função `Is64BitApp()` eu descobri [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3782556/8133067))*

Confirmei então que o SO era 64-bit, mas a aplicação não era, apesar do *Target CPU* do meu projeto estar marcado como **AnyCPU**. Foi então que notei a opção *Prefer 32-bit*, logo abaixo da opção *Target CPU*, em *Project properties* > *Compile*, que já veio marcada quando criei o projeto. Desmarquei essa opção e aí a aplicação passou a executar como 64-bit.

Tentei novamente acessar a chave do registro e dessa vez ela foi achada, mas aí passou a dar a exceção `Requested registry access is not allowed`, porque eu estava tentando acessar `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` com um usuário comum. Executei o Visual Studio como administrador e finalmente funcionou.

A única coisa que não funcionou foi a exibição do valor retornado em um `MsgBox`, como você havia feito, porque, como esse valor é do tipo `REG_MULTI_SZ`, o tipo retornado foi `String()`.

**EDIT:**
Depois eu descobri que nem precisaria ter criado a função `Is64BitApp()`, porque, além da propriedade `Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem` que usei no código, existe também a propriedade `Environment.Is64BitProcess`:

> Environment.Is64BitProcess Property
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitprocess.aspx

Após essa pergunta o usuário **jnmoura** fez outra, que também respondi, que complementa um pouco essa, então deixarei aqui como referência:

> [Acessar chave 64-bit no Registry do Windows através de aplicação 32-bit](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/283006/86952)

Comment: Fiz os procedimentos, deixei o todo em 32bit não deu certo, passei todo para 64 bit, porem quando vou preencher o datagrid, fica o valor "System.String[]"

Comment: Como eu disse na resposta, o retorno do valor será um array de String, então você tem que checar o `Length` do array e percorrer cada item do array, ou juntar todos os itens em um único string: `String.Join("; ", ValorRegistro)`.

Comment: Eu fiz o Procedimento funcionou no caminho: 

"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\{5D1CD90A-7DD6-47AC-A40F-794E920B96DB}"

Mas neste caminho nao:

"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList". Minha maquina deve estar com problema.. Obrigado Pela Ajuda..

Answer (score 1):

Deixei dessa forma:

```
 Private Sub ObterTipoDaRede()
    Dim pRegKey As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine
    pRegKey = pRegKey.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\NewNetworks")
    Dim val As Object = pRegKey.GetValue("NetworkList")
    Me.teste = val
End Sub


Public Sub Preencher_Grid_dgvDadosComputador(Grid As Object)
    With Grid
        .Rows.Add("Nome_Do_Computador ", Me.NomeMaquina)
        .Rows.Add("Nome_Domínio ", Me.DominioMaquina)
        .Rows.Add("Pasta_(Moura_)", Me.PastaMoura)
        .Rows.Add("Firewall_Redes/Domínio", Me.FirewallRedesDominio)
        .Rows.Add("Firewall_Redes/Privadas", Me.FirewallRedesPrivadas)
        .Rows.Add("Firewall_Redes/Publicas", Me.FireWallRedesPublicasConvidadas)
        .Rows.Add("teste", Me.teste)
    End With
End Sub
```

No Construtor chamo o sub

```
Public Sub New()

    ObterTipoDaRede()

End Sub
```

E no load do formulario eu chamo o procedimento de preencher o datagrid

```
 Dim Analise As New Analisar()


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Analise.Preencher_Grid_dgvDadosComputador(dgvDadosComputador)

End Sub
```

Comment: No procedimento `ObterTipoDaRede()` você pode mudar a última linha para: `Me.teste = String.Join("; ", val)`, assim junta a lista de strings em um único string.