# Acessar chave 64-bit no Registry do Windows através de aplicação 32-bit

Tags: windows, vb.net, 64-bits, x64

Preciso pegar informações referentes à rede para listar em uma aplicação que estou fazendo, porém estou com um problema ao acessar o *Registry* do Windows por causa da preferência do projeto.

Caminho: Clicar com o botão direito do mouse em cima da classe, clique em propriedades, e logo depois em compilador.

Note que abaixo do campo Target CPU, tem um CheckBox (Prefer 32-bit)

Se essa opção estiver ticada meu código não funciona em sistema 64 bits, porém se eu desabilitar minha aplicação não funciona na máquina 32 bits. Se eu comentar todos os procedimentos que buscam valores no regedit, a aplicação funciona em ambas.

Gostaria de saber se consigo fazer o acesso a chave de registro tanto em 64bits como em 32 bits.

Segue o código:

```
  Public Sub ObterTipoDaRede(ByVal NomeConfiguracao As String, ByVal  _
 NomeConfiguracaoDois As String)
    Dim NomeDaRede As String
    Dim regKey
    Dim lDatas As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, DateTime))

    'If Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem Then

    'Else
    regKey = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles")
    'End If

    Try
        For Each SubK In regKey.GetSubKeyNames

            Dim value = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\" + SubK)
            Dim data = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(value.ToString, "DateLastConnected", Nothing)
            Dim dt As DateTime = ObterDataDoUltimoAcesso(data)

            lDatas.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Date)(SubK, dt))
        Next

        lDatas = lDatas.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Value).ToList
        Dim t = lDatas.First
        Dim chave = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\" + t.Key)
        Dim nomeRede As String = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(chave.ToString, "ProfileName", Nothing)
        Dim tipoRede As String = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(chave.ToString, "Category", Nothing)

        NomeDaRede = nomeRede
        Select Case tipoRede
            Case 0
                Me.PerfilDaRede = "Publica"
            Case 1
                Me.PerfilDaRede = "Privada"
            Case 2
                Me.PerfilDaRede = "Dominio"
        End Select

        Me.PreencherGriddgvDadosComputador(NomeConfiguracao, NomeDaRede, "Ok")
        Me.PreencherGriddgvDadosComputador(NomeConfiguracaoDois, Me.PerfilDaRede, "Ok")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Teste", vbInformation)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: `Se essa opção estiver ticada meu código não funciona, porém se eu desabilitar minha aplicação não funciona na máquina 32 bits.` Se eu entendi bem o seu código não funciona independente de a opção estar ativada ou não.

Comment: Se ela não estiver ticada, funciona em sistemas 64 bits, mas em sistemas 32 bits não funciona.Qualquer procedimento que eu criar para acessar o regedit para obter um valor não consigo executar em ambos sistemas.

Answer (score 2):

Na pergunta você disse:
*Se essa opção estiver ticada meu código não funciona em sistema 64 bits, porém se eu desabilitar minha aplicação não funciona na máquina 32 bits.*

Na verdade, se o valor do campo *Target CPU* for **AnyCPU**, e a opção *Prefer 32-bit* **não** estiver marcada, o seu programa vai se adaptar ao sistema em que estiver rodando: Se o sistema for 32-bit, seu programa será executado como 32-bit, se o sistema for 64-bit, seu programa será executado como 64-bit. Mas se a opção *Prefer 32-bit* estiver marcada, seu programa será executado como 32-bit, mesmo que o sistema seja 64-bit.

O problema é que nos sistemas Windows de 64-bit, se o seu programa for 32-bit, ele será executado automaticamente em um subsistema chamado **[WOW64](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64)** (*Windows 32-bit on Windows 64-bit*), e no caso do *Registry* do Windows há algo chamado **Registry Redirector**, que intercepta as chamadas ao *Registry* e as redireciona para o local correto, baseado na arquitetura da aplicação (32 ou 64 bits).

Mais sobre o assunto nos links abaixo:

> Running 32-bit Applications
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384249.aspx
>
> Registry Redirector
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx

Hoje ao pesquisar para responder sua pergunta, eu descobri que desde o .NET Framework 4.0, há uma opção nas classes de manipulação do *Registry* do Windows que permite acessar uma chave 64-bit através de uma aplicação 32-bit, ou seja, uma opção que desabilita temporariamente o redirecionador do Registry:

> Método **RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey (RegistryHive, RegistryView)**
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey.aspx
>
> Enumeração **RegistryView**
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/microsoft.win32.registryview.aspx
>
> **Membros**
>   *RegistryView.**Default*** -> *A exibição padrão.*
>   *RegistryView.**Registry32*** -> *A exibição de 32 bits.*
>   *RegistryView.**Registry64*** -> *A exibição de 64 bits.*
>
> **Comentários**
>   *Na versão de 64 bits do Windows, as partes do registro são armazenadas separadamente para aplicativos de 32 bits e 64 bits. Há um modo de exibição de 32 bits para aplicativos de 32 bits e um modo de exibição de 64 bits para aplicativos de 64 bits.*
>
> *Você pode especificar um modo de exibição de registro ao usar os métodos `OpenBaseKey` e `OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive, String, RegistryView)` e a propriedade `FromHandle` em um objeto `RegistryKey`.*
>
> *Se você solicitar um modo de exibição de 64 bits em um sistema operacional de 32 bits, as chaves serão retornadas no modo de exibição de 32 bits.*

Alterando o seu código para usar esse método, e acessar as chaves 64-bit mesmo através de uma aplicação 32-bit:

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32

' [...]

   Public Sub ObterTipoDaRede(NomeConfiguracao As String, NomeConfiguracaoDois As String)

      Const NomeChaveProfiles = 
         "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles"

      Dim chaveBase As RegistryKey
      Dim chaveProfiles As RegistryKey
      Dim chaveProfile As RegistryKey
      Dim listaDatas As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, DateTime))

      ' Se você solicitar um modo de exibição de 64 bits em um sistema operacional
      ' de 32 bits, as chaves serão retornadas no modo de exibição de 32 bits.
      chaveBase = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine,
                                          RegistryView.Registry64)
      chaveProfiles = chaveBase.OpenSubKey(NomeChaveProfiles)

      For Each nomeChaveProfile In chaveProfiles.GetSubKeyNames
         chaveProfile = chaveBase.OpenSubKey(NomeChaveProfiles & "\" + nomeChaveProfile)
         Dim dataFormatoBinario = chaveProfile.GetValue("DateLastConnected", Nothing)
         Dim dt As DateTime = ObterDataDoUltimoAcesso(dataFormatoBinario)

         listaDatas.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Date)(nomeChaveProfile, dt))
      Next

      listaDatas = listaDatas.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Value).ToList()
      Dim primeiroItem = listaDatas.First()
      chaveProfile = chaveBase.OpenSubKey(NomeChaveProfiles & "\" + primeiroItem.Key)
      Dim nomeRede As String = chaveProfile.GetValue("ProfileName", Nothing)
      Dim tipoRede As String = chaveProfile.GetValue("Category", Nothing)

      Select Case tipoRede
         Case 0 : Me.PerfilDaRede = "Publica"
         Case 1 : Me.PerfilDaRede = "Privada"
         Case 2 : Me.PerfilDaRede = "Dominio"
      End Select

   End Sub
```